# Material UI MenuItem not showing selected item with hardcoded values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui `MenuItem` like the following and noticing following issue. I have hardcoded the `Yes` or `No` values and on the UI, my dropdown looks like following:

**Image 1:**

[image]

When I click on dropdown icon, it shows me the following:

**Image 2:**

[image]

When i select `Yes` or `No`,my selection doesn't stays on the screen and after selecting , it goes back to look exactly like Image 1. Why it is happening? I noticed that this is happening with hardcoded values only. All other places where I am displaying dynamic data via api call is showing the selected item on screen.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<CustomSelectDropdown name="yesornofordata" type="select" placeholder="Is the data approved?"/>

const CustomSelectDropdown = ({
    placeholder,
    disabled,
    ...props
}) => {
const [field, meta] = useField(props);

const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";


    return (
    <div>
    <InputLabel id="selectLabel">{placeholder}</InputLabel>
    <Field
        labelId={placeholder}
        {...field}
        disabled={disabled}
        as={StyledSelect}
        error={!!errorText}>
        <MenuItem  data-selected-value={'Y'} onClick={handleSelectedAnswer}>Yes</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem  data-selected-value={'N'} onClick={handleSelectedAnswer}>No</MenuItem> 
    </Field>
    </div>
    );
};
```

Added code for the function :

```
const handleSelectedAnswer = event => {
    const { selectedValue } = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    console.log("Storing selected answer in session storage ")
    sessionStorage.setItem("selectedAnswer", selectedValue)
}
```

Comment: What is the code for handleSelectedAnswer? Also, you have a typo for the first handleSelectedAnswer (you spelled it handleSelecte**T**Answer).

Comment: @Jake I added the code for the function in the post. Please take a look. This might not be related to my issue? Also, I corrected the typo.It happened while pasting my code.Please let me know if there are any questions I can answer.

Comment: So you're saving the value to session storage, but I don't see where you're accessing session storage to define the field value

Comment: An example of how to do this is on the MUI page - https://material-ui.com/components/menus/

Comment: How can I use it from sessionStorage to display `Yes` or `No` in the menu? I remember looking at the link you shared and all examples are not displaying the selected item there. Please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks !

Comment: It depends on how you've constructed your <Field> component. If it were an MUI <Select> component, then you would just set the `value` prop to be the value stored in session storage.

Comment: Could you share an example of MUI <Select> component with `value` prop? I don't mind changing it since it is just going to be a hard coded value of `Yes` or `No`

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/selects/